# How to deblur a image matrix blured by two circulant matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, image-processing, circulant-matrices

We suppose an image matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_2}$ is blurred by two circulant matrices $\Phi_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_1},\Phi_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2\times n_2}$. We can observe the blurred matrix $Y$ as:
$$Y=\Phi_1 X\Phi_2$$
We suppose the band width of the circulant matrices is $2K$, each non-zero element is generated from a gaussian distribution$N(0,\sigma^2)$. And $\sigma$ is known. How can we recover the original image?

Comment: This might only be a bit helpful tip to you as i did something similar long ago: Consider transforming to Fourier domain as Circulant matrices have interesting properties. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Other_properties

Comment: @AshutoshGupta Thanks,. But I want to know how to deal with unknown elements in the matrix $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$?

Comment: If you only know Y, then you have an ill-posed problem. Many combinations of X and the two Phi can lead to the same X. You need additional constraints on X.